# What good is eSATA without a power source?

Tags: esata

What good is an eSATA connection on the outside of my PC with no access to power. Without a power source it seems useless.  Am I not thinking this through correctly — is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: External eSATA drive enclosures have separate power supplies.

Comment: I think there are eSATA drive enclosures that also use USB for power.

Comment: [Power can be provided over an eSATA-compatible connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#eSATAp); that's called [eSATAp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATAp) (along with many other names drawing on the combination of eSATA and power).

Answer (score 3):

> What good is an eSATA connection on the outside of my PC with no access
>   to power. Without a power source it seems useless.
>   Am I not thinking this through correctly

You are somewhat correct but you miss that most eSATA devices will have their own power source. If you expect it to use it as a faster version of an USB external 2½ drive then you are right, however:

- For small external drives you often can use an USB cable to supply power.
- Some eSATA port come as a combiport with eSATA and USB and supply there on power. Thesecan be used with many drives or eSATA pendrive.
- For larger drives you still need an external PSU. (Same as with external 3½ inch USB drives).
- eSATA might very well connect to external towers (with their own dozen of drives and their own PSU).

If you only want to compare it to the easy portable small USB drives and you do not have one of the combined USB+eSATA conenctions: then yes, in that specific case you are right.

Comment: Note also [eSATAp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATAp).

Comment: Good point.  (Damn, I even posted it from a laptop with such a port).